# PHP form inside other form, how to multi select out put result to input text

Tags: php, html

Here is the form

form.php

```
     <form name='formONE' action='form.php'>
        <select name='multiselect[]' method='post'>
           <option name='1'>one</option>
           <option name='2'>tow</option>
           <option name='3'>three</option>
           <option name='4'>four</option>
        </select>
       <input type='submit' value='choosed' />
     </form>
   <form name='formTOW' action='form.php'>
      <input type='text' name='text1' />
      <input type='text' name='text2' />
      <input type='text' name='text3' />
      <input type='text' name='text4' />
      <input type='text' name='selectedone' value='
             <? foreach($_post['multiselect'] as $slct){print ", $slct";}' />
     <input type='submit' value='save'/>
   </form>
```

Here, on **fromONE** the user will select the options(some of option will be selected means selective) after the selection and submit the data will be passed to the form named **formTOW** input **name = selectedone** and after i submit **formTOW** data will pass to database.

but now here on **formTOW** if i input some value but in last if i select some data from **formONE** and submit the data of **formTOW** will be ears

here i want the **formONE** sumbit to do not make any change or effect on formTOW

regards

Comment: You can't put a form inside a form.

Comment: then what i should do to solve problem, here....

Comment: idia is i have multi select inside form i want to pass it one input with out any effect on form, do i need javascript???

Comment: If you don't want to use javascript you can use the forms side by side. But it is just as easy to put everything in one form. Just ignore what you don't need when you evaluate the form values.

Comment: actully, in one form there is a selective option the user will select multi option, and my main form which that input is inside it will post the value of multioptions been selected to database with ',' exp
1,2 how i can set such type of senior in one form

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a form inside a form, this is just not allowed in HTML.

If you don't want to use javascript you can use the forms side by side. But it is just as easy to put everything in one form. Just ignore what you don't need when you evaluate the form values.

```
<form name='form' action='form.php'>
  <input type='text' name='text1' />
  <input type='text' name='text2' />
  <input type='text' name='text3' />
  <input type='text' name='text4' />
  <input type='submit' value='save'/>
</form>

<form name='form1' action='form.php'>
    <select name='multiselect[]' method='post'>
       <option name='1'>one</option>
       <option name='2'>tow</option>
       <option name='3'>three</option>
       <option name='4'>four</option>
    </select>
    <input type='text' name='selectedone' value='
            <? echo implode(", ", $_POST['multiselect']); ?> />
    <input type='submit' value='TransferToTnputTextFromSelect'/>
</form>
```

Comment: i have used, but the problem is if i submit form(formONE) the (fromTOW) data will be erase and clean, i have edit my question as ur answer